# Wicket lazy load a ListView

Tags: wicket

Is it possible to lazy load a `ListView` in Wicket?
Which means for me that inside `populateItem` can I load and display `Item 0` and when `Item 0` is rendered then proceed to `Item 1`. Currently I have to wait until all `Items` are processed inside `populateItem`.

Comment: You could render the items using `AjaxLazyLoadPanel`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As RobAu mentioned you can achieve this using `AjaxLazyLoadPanel`(wicket-extension) with minimal changes in your coding . Let's consider you are having `Item` as a model.

```
        List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        itemList.add(new Item());
        itemList.add(new Item());

        ListView<Item>itemListView = new ListView<Item>("itemListView",ItemList) {
            @Override
            protected void populateItem(final ListItem<Item> listItem) {
            listItem.add(new AjaxLazyLoadPanel("ViewItemPanel") {
                @Override
                public Component getLazyLoadComponent(String s) {
                     // Add a seperate panel if you are listing out many values
                    return new ItemPanel(s,listItem.getModelObject());
                }
            });
            }
        };
        add(itemListView);
```

`ItemPanel` its to seperate the component if you have to show many.

Comment: While this is working, I achieve strange results, for example Strings and Labels were rendered first and the image later on, which breaks the flow of my website.